# Надо отсортировать/объединить/склеить два объекта

Tags: java

Есть вот такой класс

```
public class UserData {
    public long UserTimestamp;
    public String UserName;
    public String UserURL;
    public int UserTimeOnPage;
        UserData(long UT, String UN, String UU, int UTOP){

        UserTimestamp=UT;
        UserName=UN;
        UserURL=UU;
        UserTimeOnPage=UTOP;
    }
}
```

Я получаю объекты из входного файла, и добавляю их в list

```
ArrayList<UserData> list=new ArrayList<UserData>(); 
        try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        // use comma as separator
                String[] country=line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                UserData current=new UserData(Long.parseLong(country[0]), country[1], country[2], Integer.parseInt(country[3]));
                list.add(current);
            }
```

Входные данные это timestamp, имя юзера, количество времени которое он провел на сайте. Если имя юзера, имя сайта и дата когда юзер был на сайте совпадают тогда надо два объекта объединить/склеить в один, подсчитав среднее время на сайте и результат бросить на консоль например.

```
пример входного файла:
1455812018,user2,wikipedia.org,100
1455812019,user10,hh.ru,30
1455812968,user3,google.com,60
1455812411,user10,hh.ru,90
1455812684,user3,vk.com,50

пример выходного файла:
user2,wikipedia.org,100
user3,google.com,60
user3,vk.com,50
user10,hh.ru,60
```

То есть два объекта слились в один

было

```
1455812019 user10 http://hh.ru 30 
 1455812411 user10 http://hh.ru 90
```

стало

```
17-FEB-2016
    user10,http://hh.ru,60
```

Comment: вам надо написать соответствующий код, который это сделает. встроенного механизма нет.

Comment: Сделайте функцию, которая будет реализовать действия, описанные вами, которая будет возвращать объект, которые тоже вами описан

Comment: Объектов может быть например 10-ть одинаковых, или 7, входные данные меняются.